# prepros always create with the name of dist

Tags: prepros

I am using prepros to minify my js file. In settings I am choosing the output file and I have activated the automatically processing. When I process single file via GUI, that works fine. But when I save my js file prepros creates a 'dist' directory and another compiled file inside. Is there any setting for this?

[image: settings]

[image: added dist directory]

Answer (score 0):

It was actually VS code that was creating directory..